# jQuery's History (and Bookmark) plugin may have a bug?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I am suspecting in file
http://github.com/tkyk/jquery-history-plugin/blob/master/samples/ajax/ajax.js

line 13 and 14

```
            load(url);
            $.history.load(url);
```

in Firefox, Chrome, and IE 8, I see that the page is loaded twice when 1, 2, or 3 is clicked on.

Is it true that line 13, "load(url);" can be removed because $.history.load(url) will trigger the function registered with $.history.init(), which does a load() already?

Can someone familiar with the package confirm this?

(This is the best Ajax History and Bookmark library I found for jQuery.  If someone knows another good one please let us know).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can remove the `load(url)` call and it'll work, what happens is that the `init` takes a callback, if the location hash changes ([which it checks every 100ms](http://github.com/tkyk/jquery-history-plugin/blob/master/jquery.history.js#L63)) it'll run that callback again.

This part:

```
$.history.init(function(url) {
  load(url == "" ? "1" : url);
});
```

That function gets run every 100ms, [if the current location hash (or `appState` in the plugin) doesn't match what it was previously](http://github.com/tkyk/jquery-history-plugin/blob/master/jquery.history.js#L67).  The `load()` call in the actual `click` handler is in addition to this, so currently it's running instantly, and 0-100ms later again.

Comment: great... you are very familiar with javascript.  A similar package that we were using had this issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3162579/why-does-really-simple-history-javascript-library-fire-off-event-twice-in-ie-but  do you know why?